# Best way of playing mkv video that is being recorded with ffmpeg in web browser

Tags: html, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm looking for a way to play a video that is being recorded with ffmpeg in a web browser preferably using HTML5 video tag.

I have this code in my page, the URL is pointing to a video file (example.mkv) that is being recorded by ffmpeg.

```
<video class="video-player" controls loop>          
            <source src="{{asset('example.mkv')}}" type="video/mp4">
            <p>Your browser does not support H.264/MP4.</p>
</video>
```

Google Chrome/Chromium can play mkv video in HTML5, but only plays the part that was loaded when page was loaded. Is it possible to continue to load the video while it is being recorded?

Answer (score 0):

First off, drop the `type="video/mp4"`... that's not accurate for your MKV.  Next, consider using WebM, which is the same Matroska container but with a subset of features... you will maximize browser compatibility this way.

Now, to do what you want, you simply need to send the data to the browser as it is encoded.  This means building a server and piping the FFmpeg out directly to the client.  No file on disk.  Chrome can then stream it just fine.